# docker compose vs docker-compose vs docker stack and env variables

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

my situation is quite simple: i have a docker-compose file which simplified looks like:

```yaml
version: '3.6'

services:
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu
    command: 'printenv'
    environment:
      BAR_ENV: "${FOO_ENV:-admin:$2y$05$kSCGQdzsuy1.htrJp.lqsOZjmF1fuDE9AURnk7szE5poFJ9gY7uPO}"
```

I need to make it working for all 3 possible deployment scenarios:

1. docker-compose
2. docker stack -c file-name.yml deploy stack-name
3. docker compose

until now i had to deal only with "docker-compose" & "docker stack deploy"  variants and all was fine

but now i have a requirement to support "docker compose" for the same file and it doesn't work:

```
dollar git:(release/3375.0) ✗ docker-compose up          
Starting dollar_ubuntu_1 ... done
Attaching to dollar_ubuntu_1
ubuntu_1  | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ubuntu_1  | HOSTNAME=23267335bcdf
ubuntu_1  | BAR_ENV=admin:$2y$05$kSCGQdzsuy1.htrJp.lqsOZjmF1fuDE9AURnk7szE5poFJ9gY7uPO
ubuntu_1  | HOME=/root
dollar_ubuntu_1 exited with code 0
➜  dollar git:(release/3375.0) ✗ docker compose up
WARN[0000] The "kSCGQdzsuy1" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
invalid interpolation format for services.ubuntu.environment.BAR_ENV: "admin:$2y$05$kSCGQdzsuy1.htrJp.lqsOZjmF1fuDE9AURnk7szE5poFJ9gY7uPO". You may need to escape any $ with another $.
```

obviously if i add extra $ like in this hint, then it works only for "docker compose" but for "docker-compose" doesn't

```
➜  dollar git:(release/3375.0) ✗ docker compose up
Attaching to dollar-ubuntu-1
dollar-ubuntu-1  | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
dollar-ubuntu-1  | HOSTNAME=3877ff3f1b27
dollar-ubuntu-1  | BAR_ENV=admin:$2y$05$kSCGQdzsuy1.htrJp.lqsOZjmF1fuDE9AURnk7szE5poFJ9gY7uPO
dollar-ubuntu-1  | HOME=/root
dollar-ubuntu-1 exited with code 0
➜  dollar git:(release/3375.0) ✗ docker-compose up
Recreating dollar-ubuntu-1 ... done
Attaching to dollar_ubuntu_1
ubuntu_1  | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ubuntu_1  | HOSTNAME=051ddae56c2f
ubuntu_1  | BAR_ENV=admin:$$2y$$05$$kSCGQdzsuy1.htrJp.lqsOZjmF1fuDE9AURnk7szE5poFJ9gY7uPO
ubuntu_1  | HOME=/root
dollar_ubuntu_1 exited with code 0
```

i played with env files to store default value of variable but it doesn't work with "docker stack"

so is there a common technique that will be supported everywhere  ?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Docker, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This sounds like something that might be better filed as a bug against the Compose Docker plugin.